# Raspberry PI 3 + L298N Rapid changing action hangs up the Pi

Tags: raspbian, raspivid

I do some research in Robotic using several machine learning algorithm.

I am using Raspi 3 with native camera module. I stack the Raspi with L298N Motor Driver. 
They are using separate power supply.

The Motor driver are using 4 pin to control the direction of the left and right servo.

I create a Nodejs script to listen for some action (Forward, right, back, left) from some port. 
Everything goes well. Camera recording works too.

A problem arise when I created a script to capture every 4 frames from the camera stream and do random action.
The stream are in 30fps. So to capture 4 frames it takes roughly 130ms, after that it has to choose a random action (Forward, right, back, left).
The Raspi hangs up after 3 cycle. I was thinking that the refresh rate was too fast, but that wasn't the case. 
Because after I added a 5 sec wait after each action, the Raspi still hangs up after 3 cycle.

The Raspi were fine if I connected the raspi output pin into some LEDS. 
The LEDs are blinking after the 4 frames captured successfully without any Raspi hang.

Any ideas?

Sorry for the bad english
Thanks

Comment: Where is the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who use Adafruit Mini Rover Chassis and using native camera. The motor will interfere the camera port. I am not sure if it's magnetic or vibration interference but you have to put some space between the PI and the chassis.